# AttributeError at:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'src'

Tags: python, django

All of sudden, I'm getting this error.
It was working till just now, but not anymore. I was just trying to get a thumbnail working which is still not working. 
my views.py

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here
            self.object.moderator = self.request.user
            self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 

            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

my medias.py

```
import json
from goose import Goose   

def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return article.top_image.src
```

Comment: Why did you edit to remove the error?? It completely neuters the question about why you are "getting this error".

Comment: @JCotton because you said it's probably not helpful to anyone, and frankly I don't think anyone is going to help me what I've asked either....sigh...

Answer (score 1):

Consider what Python is telling you about the error. Your `article` object simply doesn't have a `top_image`. No top_image, no `src` attribute. Make sure your article has an image, which probably means uploading something since you are calling it "media".

This isn't a programming error. Though you should consider adding some error checking for this type of situation. Unless the Article object requires a top_image and can't be saved/instantiated without one, it's likely someone will program an Article without an image and you'll see this error again someday. Also, you assigned the `resposne` (typo?) variable and never use it.

Here's how you can replicate your error, in a shell, no Django required:

```
>>> top_image = None
>>> top_image.src
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'src'
```

Comment: yes, this is why I don't understand. the article has to image, it was working till just today. So even if I go back to previous state, same error will show up? I just installed bunch of image tools(for PIL) on my ubuntu.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/104900/it-was-working-yesterday-i-swear-what-can-you-do

Comment: turns out, my article is from imgur and imgur is down for some reason right now. How would one prevent such error shows up when the site is down? I should use try and except in media.py right?

Comment: This missing media issue is beyond the scope of this question and honestly probably not helpful to others. You had an uploaded piece of media and now you don't. That's not a coding issue and so reverting your code is irrelevant; you'll get the same error. Installing PIL and other tools is also most likely irrelevant. Test this: upload or somehow *assign* a `top_image` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @JCotton, yes I realized that. do you know how to prevent such error instead of getting error?

Comment: Ah Imgur. Don't couple your code so tightly to third-party APIs. `try/except` umm...can help, but you need a real strategy for writing a robust application. Again, beyond scope.

Comment: Yes I was thinking try/except as well, but not sure if it will cover all my requirements. will if/else help? like if image exists it displays else nothing,,,,or will this give same error .....